# converting edgelist to two-mode network matrix

Tags: r, igraph, data-manipulation, adjacency-matrix, sna

`HAVE` is an edge-list for an odd two mode network. People in `actor` are major award-winning actors; people in `supporter` are other actors who performed in one or more `films` as a supporting role. Note: `actor` includes *some* members of `supporter` but not all, which is why I am treating this as two-mode data.

```
index   actor   supporter   films
1       f1      f4          2
2       f1      f2          1
3       f1      f7          6
4       f1      f5          5
5       f2      f6          6
6       f2      f3          3
7       f3      f1          9
8       f3      f4          1
9       f3      f2          4
```

`WANT` is a two-mode adjacency matrix made from `HAVE` - row names represent all ids in `actor`; column names include every name in both `actor` and `supporter`.

```
    f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7
f1  0   1   0   2   5   0   6
f2  0   0   3   0   0   6   0
f3  9   4   0   1   0   0   0
```

How do I transform `HAVE` to `WANT`? This process is complicated by the fact that **(a)** each mode has ids with an identical naming scheme and **(b)** asymmetry (e.g., f2 led and f1 supported once, but f1 never led in a film where f2 supported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use your favorite `reshape`r function:

```
dat <- read.table(text ="index   actor   supporter   films
1       f1      f4          2
2       f1      f2          1
3       f1      f7          6
4       f1      f5          5
5       f2      f6          6
6       f2      f3          3
7       f3      f1          9
8       f3      f4          1
9       f3      f2          4", header=TRUE)

adj <- reshape(dat[,-1], v.names = "films", idvar = "actor", 
               timevar = "supporter", direction = "wide")
adj[is.na(adj)] <- 0
adj[,order(colnames(adj))]
#   actor films.f1 films.f2 films.f3 films.f4 films.f5 films.f6 films.f7
# 1    f1        0        1        0        2        5        0        6
# 5    f2        0        0        3        0        0        6        0
# 7    f3        9        4        0        1        0        0        0
```